# Add/Remove Programs...I'm not sure what to make of the programs listed...

Tags: raspbian-jessie

Just as the title reads,  I am trying to figure out the Add/Remove Programs. I see ALL KINDS off different software,  but unsure of what to make of it all. There's science,  publishing,  electronics,  programming,  other,  multimedia,  network,  documentation,  localization,  legacy,  Internet,  graphics,  games,  fonts,  KDE Desktop,  GNOME desktop,  communication, administration tools,  accessories... I would like to know what all these things do. Since it's not Microsoft,  I can't decipher all this. The obvious ones like Internet,  fonts,  games,  administration tools... Stuff like that I have figured out. However I don't know what GNOME desktop is... Or KDE desktop,  nor science,  legacy,  etc. Any knowledge of these programs and what they do would be appreciated. I have looked and looked and looked... And I can't find any answers on this... Only fixes for problems with them... I want to know what they are.

I am running Raspbian Jessie with the up to date kernel an dither updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Add / Remove Software" window provides a lot of helpful information about each package.

Select a category on the left, and then select a package on the right. It'll provide a detailed description in the panel at the bottom, including links and references to more info.

[image]

You can find all that information and more on [debian.org](http://debian.org), in multiple formats.

- [by category](https://packages.debian.org/stable/)
- [compressed format](https://packages.debian.org/stable/allpackages?format=txt.gz) - *(one large text file)*
- [full info](https://packages.debian.org/stable/allpackages) - *(one long page, might take awhile to load)*

Comment: thank you. So,  are these packages already installed in the image installation process, or do I have to select a package and them select "apply"?

Comment: @BadgerTrucking No problem. Only the "checked" ones are installed. Otherwise, check the one you want, click apply, enter a password (if prompted), and it should install it.

Comment: OK. Now will I see these programs in the start menu?

Comment: @BadgerTrucking Yep, they should add shortcuts in the Menu, although I can't say for sure that they _all_ do (there's a ton in there, and some of them may be addons for other programs and only show when those programs are open... I'm not sure).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the customizable script from here.
https://github.com/techworked/raspberrypi-remove-apps

The script lists all preinstalled apps. Comments those not to be remove and execute. Will do the uninstallation process automatically.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to remove any programs, they want to have information on programs they have installed.